# How to access firebase realtime database according to the rules using http requests

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, get

I have made a webapp with javascript and i have used firebase realtime database and it works perfectly. Who have permissions to write only that user can write and who have permissions to read only that user can read. But when i try to use this database in a vue project so that user cannot access the data i always get a 401 unauthorized error. Is there any way to send the http requests so firebase can understand the privileges.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use [Firebase Auth API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth) for that.

Comment: So i should send request with these auth ? 

var defaultAuth = firebase.auth();

url.json?auth= defaultAuth 

Like this??

Comment: i guess you should use one of auth methods available (don't forget to enable it in backend). for example, firebase.auth().signInAnonymously(); and then use event   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function() { ... } ) to catch successful login and do what you need. probably with API as well. on backend side you should then set rules to allow read / write depending on uid

Comment: Exactly. The app that i have built without http requests works perfectly. I have set up all. firebase auth login logout all is ok. The problem is with http requests.

I have tried ( Retrieve ID tokens on clients ) but its so confusing still getting errors :(

Comment: i have solved using this Authenticate with an access token.

Thanks for your time